# Negative bottom margins "stickey footer" has annoying vertical scrollbar if <h> element involved

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I got a sticky footer that is implemented with "Negative bottom margins" technique(does not use flex because need to support IE)

It works fine until I has some element like `<h>` or `<p>` in it then it renders with a annoying vertical scroll bar.

My temporal workaround is use `<span>` instead but the layout would be sightly different. What is the best solution here?

```css
html,
body,
form {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* Equal to height of footer */
  /* But also accounting for potential margin-bottom of last child */
  margin-bottom: -30px;
}

.footer,
.push {
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>I am the header</h1><!--I needs to use span here-->
      <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <p>I am the footer</p><!--I needs to use span here-->
    </footer>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a JSFiddle with your code and the fixes. Here's what I added:

```
.wrapper {
      padding: 1px 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
 .footer,
 .push {
      height: 30px;
      overflow: hidden;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/97hsqLav/

You had two main problems:

1. The problem with the margins was caused by "Margin collapse". Basically start and end margins are summed with the parent's in some cases. Setting a padding of 1px resolves this (set it to top AND bottom to ensure both ways). The additional `box-sizing` is needed, so the height stays 100% (instead of 100% + 2px paddings)
2. The text in the footer was higher than 30px, so the footer itself was a couple of pixels too tall (thus triggering the scrollbar). `Overflow: hidden` fixes this by cutting off everything that goes over 30px

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    .footer,   
>       .push {
>    height: 30px;
> }
> ```

This is the issue you have limited the height of the footer to 30 pixels if you are entering text that exceeds 30px, the browser will automatically scroll it to show all content try increasing it to 60px.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
html, body,form {
/*height: 100%;*/
margin: 0;
font-weight:normal;
}
.wrapper {
width:90%;
margin:0 auto;
}
.footer{
position:absolute;
width:90%;
bottom:0;
left:5%;
right:5%;
}
.innerFooter{
display:block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<div class="wrapper">
<h1>I am the header</span> //I needs to use span here</h1>
<div class="push"></div>
<div>
<p>
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.

The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
</p>
</div>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
<div class="innerFooter">
<p>
<span>I am the footer</span>
<span>I needs to use span here</span>
</p> 
</div>

</footer>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```